# Non-blocking reverse proxy with netty

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to write a non-blocking proxy with netty 4.1. I have a "FrontHandler" which handles incoming connections, and then a "BackHandler" which handles outgoing ones. I'm following the HexDumpProxyHandler (https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/ed4a89082bb29b9e7d869c5d25d6b9ea8fc9d25b/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java#L67)

In this code    I have found:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (outboundChannel.isActive()) {
        outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {, I've seen:
```

Meaning that the incoming message is only written if the outbound client connection is already ready. This is obviously not ideal in a HTTP proxy case, so I am thinking what would be the best way to handle it.

I am wondering if disabling auto-read on the front-end connection (and only trigger reads manually once the outgoing client connection is ready) is a good option. I could then enable autoRead over the child socket again, in the "channelActive" event of the backend handler. However, I am not sure about how many messages would I get in the handler for each "read()" invocation (using HttpDecoder, I assume I would get the initial HttpRequest, but I'd really like to avoid getting the subsequent HttpContent / LastHttpContent messages until I manually trigger the read() again and enable autoRead over the channel).

Another option would be to use a Promise to get the Channel from the client ChannelPool:

```
private void setCurrentBackend(HttpRequest request) {
    pool.acquire(request, backendPromise);

    backendPromise.addListener((FutureListener<Channel>) future -> {
        Channel c = future.get();
        if (!currentBackend.compareAndSet(null, c)) {
            pool.release(c);
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    });
}
```

and then do the copying from input to output thru that promise. Eg:

```
private void handleLastContent(ChannelHandlerContext frontCtx, LastHttpContent lastContent) {
    doInBackend(c -> {
        c.writeAndFlush(lastContent).addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
            if (future.isSuccess()) {
                future.channel().read();
            } else {
                pool.release(c);
                frontCtx.close();
            }
        });
    });
}
private void doInBackend(Consumer<Channel> action) {
    Channel c = currentBackend.get();
    if (c == null) {
        backendPromise.addListener((FutureListener<Channel>) future -> action.accept(future.get()));
    } else {
        action.accept(c);
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure about how good it is to keep the promise there forever and do all the writes from "front" to "back" by adding listeners to it. I'm also not sure about how to instance the promise so that the operations are performed in the right thread... right now I'm using:

```
backendPromise = group.next().<Channel> newPromise(); // bad
// or
backendPromise = frontCtx.channel().eventLoop().newPromise(); // OK?
```

(where group is the same eventLoopGroup as used in the ServerBootstrap of the frontend).

If they're not handled thru the right thread, I assume it could be problematic to have the "else { }" optimization in the "doInBackend" method to avoid using the Promise and write to the channel directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no-autoread approach doesn't work by itself, because the HttpRequestDecoder creates several messages even if only one read() was performed.

I have solved it by using chained CompletableFutures.

Comment: I'm facing a very similar problem: Client -[http]-> Netty -[websockets]-> Backend and I have to wait for the websockets handshake to complete before I can send data. It seems unnecessary complicated to implement something like. Could you please describe what you did in more detail? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a similar proxy application based on the MQTT protocol. So it was basically used to create a real-time chat application. The application that I had to design however was asynchronous in nature so I naturally did not face any such problem. Because in case the

```
outboundChannel.isActive() == false
```

then I can simply keep the messages in a queue or a persistent DB and then process them once the outboundChannel is up. However, since you are talking about an HTTP application, so this means that the application is synchronous in nature meaning that the client cannot keep on sending packets until the outboundChannel is up and running. So the option you suggest is that the packet will only be read once the channel is active and you can manually handle the message reads by disabling the auto read in `ChannelConfig`.

However, what I would like to suggest is that you should check if the outboundChannel is active or not. In case the channel is active, send he packet forward for processing. In case the channel is not active, you should reject the packet by sending back a response similar to **Error404**

Along with this you should configure your client to keep on retrying sending the packets after certain intervals and accordingly handle what needs to be done in case the channel takes too long a time to become active and become readable.  Manually handling channelRead is generally not preferred and is an anti pattern. You should let Netty handle that for you in the most efficient way.

Comment: I cannot send 404 back to the client, as the client is not (and should not be) aware of the fact that there's a backend server that needs to be connected to...